# Google Chrome Font Changed (Win 10)

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Randomly my font has changed on Google Chrome, and I'm not even sure how. I can barely read anything. It currently looks like this:

[image]

I'm currently using Windows 10 Pro and latest version of Google Chrome.

Any advice will be appreciated.